# Having problems iterating over dict in Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

There seem to be a million questions (and answers) about this, but none of them are working for me.

I've got something like this:

```
test_dict = {'name':'Joe'}
return render_to_response('home.html',test_dict,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template, I'm trying to do this:

```
{% for k,v in test_dict.items %}
  Hello {{ v }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

But no luck. On the other hand, this works:

```
Hello {{ name }}
```

(No for loop). I must be missing something really obvious?

**EDIT**
In response to the first answer, I've also tried this:

```
test_dict = {'name':'Joe'}
data = {'test_dict':test_dict}

return render_to_response('home.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in the template:

```
{% block content %}
  {% for k, v in data.items %}
    Hello {{ v }} <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Still nothing showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you would want something like

```
data = {'test_dict':test_dict}
return render_to_response('home.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments)

> A dictionary of values to add to the template context.

So in your example, test_dict is injected into the template context.  Think of it working like this:

```
template = Template()
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    template[k] = v
```

So test_dict is not injected into the template's context, but the keys and values of test_dict are.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It's still not showing any data for me, though: test_dict = {'name':'Joe'} data = {'test_dict':test_dict} return render_to_response('ga_home.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 0):

When:

```
test_dict = {'name':'Joe'}
data = {'test_dict':test_dict}

return render_to_response('home.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Use:

```
{% for k, v in test_dict.items %}
```